# Receiving 404.0 error when downloading a file on IIS 7 and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: iis, download, http-status-code-404

I have an application which allows the users to upload and download files. The upload code looks like this:
[View]

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />

<p />

<input type="submit" value="Upload" style="font-size:1em" />
</form>
```

[Controller]

```
public ActionResult Index(string id, FormCollection formCollection, HttpPostedFileBase file, int?    FileID)

string filePath = "c:\\sandbox\\" + id + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") + extension;
file.SaveAs(filePath);
```

The upload works fine. However, when I try to download the file just uploaded to "The Sandbox", I receive a 404 error. Here is the download code:

[View]

```
 <a href="/AdjClaim/Download/@f.ID">@f.Name </a>
```

[Controller]

```
return File(a.FilePath, a.ContentType, a.Name); //File path is c:\Sandbox\filename
```

The application works flawlessly on my dev box, but fails when ported to IIS 7.5 box. Any thoughts would be extremely appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: ...what are the values for a.ContentType and a.Name?

Comment: Content Type is application/pdf. Name is Test.pdf.

Comment: Can you verify that the route is being executed on the IIS 7.5 box? If you change the return type from FilePathResult to ActionResult and then return a view as if it were a normal page does it work?

Comment: Also, in looking at the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492593.aspx) it appears the filename must be included in the first argument like this: File(String.Format("{0}/{1}", a.FilePath, a.Name), a.ContentType, a.Name);

Comment: You nailed it! I changed the controller to return a View instead of a File (view just says "Hello World". Works on dev box, but not on IIS server. Of course, now the question is why?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem!

When testing on dev box, the controller/action is located directly off the root. However, when deploying to the IIS box, the web site is placed in a sub-folder (xxxxxxx_deploy). Since the link to the controller action does not include the IIS sub-folder, it works on local box.

Thank you Mike!